# Identifying pure functions in python

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, purely-functional

I have a decorator `@pure` that registers a function as pure, for example:

```
@pure
def rectangle_area(a,b):
    return a*b


@pure
def triangle_area(a,b,c):
    return ((a+(b+c))(c-(a-b))(c+(a-b))(a+(b-c)))**0.5/4
```

Next, I want to identify a newly defined pure function

```
def house_area(a,b,c):
    return rectangle_area(a,b) + triangle_area(a,b,c)
```

Obviously `house_area` is pure, since it only calls pure functions.

How can I discover all pure functions automatically (perhaps by using `ast`)

Comment: Is `operator.add()` - `+` a pure function?

Comment: Great question, lets assume all pure operators (`+`,`-`,`==`,`*`,`/`,...) are registered as pure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming operators are all pure, then essentially you only need to check all the functions calls. This can indeed be done with the ast module.

First I defined the `pure` decorator as:

```
def pure(f):
    f.pure = True
    return f
```

Adding an attribute telling that it's pure, allows skipping early or "forcing" a function to identify as pure. This is useful if you'd need a function like `math.sin` to identify as pure. *Additionally since you can't add attributes to builtin functions.*

```
@pure
def sin(x):
    return math.sin(x)
```

All in all. Use the `ast` module to visit all the nodes. Then for each `Call` node check whether the function being called is pure.

```
import ast

class PureVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self, visited):
        super().__init__()
        self.pure = True
        self.visited = visited

    def visit_Name(self, node):
        return node.id

    def visit_Attribute(self, node):
        name = [node.attr]
        child = node.value
        while child is not None:
            if isinstance(child, ast.Attribute):
                name.append(child.attr)
                child = child.value
            else:
                name.append(child.id)
                break
        name = ".".join(reversed(name))
        return name

    def visit_Call(self, node):
        if not self.pure:
            return
        name = self.visit(node.func)
        if name not in self.visited:
            self.visited.append(name)
            try:
                callee = eval(name)
                if not is_pure(callee, self.visited):
                    self.pure = False
            except NameError:
                self.pure = False
```

Then check whether the function has the `pure` attribute. If not get code and check if all the functions calls can be classified as pure.

```
import inspect, textwrap

def is_pure(f, _visited=None):
    try:
        return f.pure
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    try:
        code = inspect.getsource(f.__code__)
    except AttributeError:
        return False

    code = textwrap.dedent(code)
    node = compile(code, "<unknown>", "exec", ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST)

    if _visited is None:
        _visited = []

    visitor = PureVisitor(_visited)
    visitor.visit(node)
    return visitor.pure
```

Note that `print(is_pure(lambda x: math.sin(x)))` doesn't work since `inspect.getsource(f.__code__)` returns code on a line by line basis. So the source returned by `getsource` would include the `print` and `is_pure` call, thus yielding `False`. *Unless those functions are overridden.*

---

To verify that it works, test it by doing:

```
print(house_area) # Prints: True
```

To list through all the functions in the current module:

```
import sys, types

for k in dir(sys.modules[__name__]):
    v = globals()[k]
    if isinstance(v, types.FunctionType):
        print(k, is_pure(v))
```

---

The `visited` list keeps track of which functions have already been verified pure. This help circumvent problems related to recursion. Since the code isn't executed, the evaluation would recursively visit `factorial`.

```
@pure
def factorial(n):
    return 1 if n == 1 else n * factorial(n - 1)
```

Note that you might need to revise the following code. Choosing another way to obtain a function from its name.

```
try:
    callee = eval(name)
    if not is_pure(callee, self.visited):
        self.pure = False
except NameError:
    self.pure = False
```

Comment: Great solution, thank you ! 
I'm puzzled as to why `is_pure(f)` is `True` where `f = lambda x: math.sin(x)` (Note that `f` is not marked as `@pure`)

Comment: And on the other hand, `is_pure(lambda x:math.sin(x))` is `False`

Comment: The first one is actually because it doesn't account for "math" then "sin" (I'll fix that now). The second problem is due to `inspect.getsource(f.__code__)`, which doesn't return `lambda x:math.sin(x)` but the whole line.

Comment: @UriGoren I fixed the first problem, but as already stated the second problem isn't directly solvable while using `inspect.getsource` (unless you manually extract a substring). However it is probably easier just to avoid passing a lambda like that, and instead do the `f = lambda ...` way if needed.